# Incrementing integer variable of global scope in Python

Tags: python, function, scope, integer, increment

I am trying to change global value `x` from within another functions scope as the following code shows,

```
x = 1
def add_one(x):
    x += 1
```

then I execute the sequence of statements on Python's interactive terminal as follows.

```
>>> x
1
>>> x += 1
>>> x
2
>>> add_one(x)
>>> x
2
```

Why is `x` still 2 and not 3?

Comment: Because `x` is a local, not a global.

Comment: You should read about scoping ... 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Answer (score 7):

Because `x` is a *local* (all function arguments are), not a global, and integers are not mutable.

So `x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1`, producing a new integer object, and `x` is rebound to that.

You can mark `x` a global in the function:

```
def add_one():
    global x
    x += 1
```

There is no point in passing in `x` as an argument here.